# Use parent CSS in a child iframe

Tags: css, iframe

I want to embed my website on external sites giving owners of that site possibility to adjust styles of my website using CSS. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parameter to the URL that triggers the embedding of an additional CSS. So for instance:

```
<iframe src="http://your.domain.com/path/to/page?useStyle=styleCode">
```

You'd have to add these additional styles yourself to your website. You could also have them create a CSS and have them host it on their site. You could include that additional stylesheet  from their site on your page based on the same parameter mentioned above.

Be careful to not have these parameters point to absolute URL directly, but use codes (like above). This to prevent hackers changing these paths into something that is hosted on an evil server that then is automatically included on your site.